# How can I lemmatize iterating on each line?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nltk, text-mining, lemmatization

everybody I'm trying to lemmatize row by row each reviews that I have, after a POS procedure.
Anyway I'm struggling a bit with this.
There is some way to do it?

Here the code:
[image]
[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Note that `for w in row["Tokenized"]` loop iterates over sentences, not over individual `(word,pos)` pairs. You need to insert  a loop over sentences, e.g. `for index, row in df3.iterrows(): for clause in row["Tokenized"]: for word, pos in clause: ...`

Comment: Ok and then what I have to pass inside the two indexes instead of w[0] and w[1]?

Comment: No problem. So I have to pass word and pos instead of w[0] and w[1]?

Comment: Honestly my problem on these loop is how to take the two values and the lemmatize. Anyway I tried to put word pos as indexes but is not working

Comment: I believe the error is caused by the Tokenizer returning a **list of lists** of `(word, pos)` pairs, instead of a simple list as your code suggests.

Comment: In your code the first iteration of the inner loop runs with `w[0] == (hotel, NN)` and `w[1] == (nice, JJ)`, which is clearly not what is intended.